# Statements about convergence in algebra operators

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $e_i = {\delta_{ij}} \in l_2$
$A_n, B_n \in \mathcal{L}(l_2)$
$A_n: {x_i} \rightarrow x_ne_1$
$B_n: {x_i} \rightarrow x_1e_n$
$\Rightarrow A_n \rightarrow 0; B_n \rightarrow 0$
$\not\exists s - lim B_n$
$A_nB_n \rightharpoonup 0$
Where s - strong operator topology. I think, that we can prove this for $\mathcal{L}(l_\infty)$. Can we reduce our $l_2$ case to this situation?

Comment: It is not true that $B_n\to0$. Not even in the sot, since $\|B_nx\|=|x_1|$ for all $n$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami thank you. But what can I do instead?

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not entirely sure of what you are trying to do.